# How to remove end-if in algorithms

Tags: conditionals, algorithms, loops

I am writing an algorithm in latex, but there are lots of `end-if` and `end-while`s in my algorithms which makes it un-professional and ugly. Is there a way to remove them from output of latex?

```
\IF{condition}  
      \IF{another condition}
          \STATE do something
          \STATE do something else
      \ELSE
          \STATE do it
      \ENDIF
\ELSE
      \IF{condition}
          \STATE do something
          \STATE do another thing
      \ELSE
          \IF{condition}
              \STATE function
          \ENDIF
      \ENDIF
\ENDIF
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest you to switch to the more versatile [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package; using the noend option, you can achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algcompatible}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\IF{condition}  
      \IF{another condition}
          \STATE do something
          \STATE do something else
      \ELSE
          \STATE do it
      \ENDIF
\ELSE
      \IF{condition}
          \STATE do something
          \STATE do another thing
      \ELSE
          \IF{condition}
              \STATE function
          \ENDIF
      \ENDIF
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `algcompatible` variant of the package to have full compatibility with the `algorithmic`'s syntax, but I'd also suggest you to change to `algpseudocode` (the syntax is pretty similar); here's your code using `algpseudocode` (the only difference is the case type used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\If{condition}  
      \If{another condition}
          \State do something
          \State do something else
      \Else
          \State do it
      \EndIf
\Else
      \If{condition}
          \State do something
          \State do another thing
      \Else
          \If{condition}
              \State function
          \EndIf
      \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```